# How to use a unified connection string to Docker container SQL Server from both local host and another container?

Tags: sql-server, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, connection-string

When I run SQL Server in a container to connect the API to it when running from a local host, I need one kind of connection string. However, when I run SQL Server and API in Docker using Docker Compose, I need a different kind of connection string.

Here is my Docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.9'

volumes:
  SqlDataStorage:
  
networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  weather.api:
    container_name: WeatherForecastApi
    image: maks0s/weather-app:6.1.0
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=8080
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS=8081
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=********
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    ports:
      - '5000:8080'
      - '5001:8081'
    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
    networks:
      - my-network
    depends_on:
      - weather.db

  weather.db:
    container_name: WeatherForecastCloudDb
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    env_file:
      - sqlconfig.env
      - sapassword.env
    ports:
      - '1439:1433'
    volumes:
      - SqlDataStorage:/var/opt/mssql
    networks:
      - my-network
```

Running SQL Server in a container, in order to connect my API to it when running from a local host, I need a connection string of the following kind:

`"Data Source=host.docker.internal,1439;Initial Catalog=WeatheForecastDb;User ID=sa;Password=**********; Trust Server Certificate=True; MultiSubnetFailover=True"`

However, when I run the SQL Server and API in Docker using Docker Compose, the connection string should be:
`"Data Source=weather.db;Initial Catalog=WeatheForecastDb;User ID=sa;Password=**********; Trust Server Certificate=True; MultiSubnetFailover=True"`

The question arises, is it possible to create some unified connection string, or will it be necessary to use ternary operators with environment variable checking to form a connection string directly at startup time in the local/container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question arises, is it possible to create some unified connection string, or will it be necessary to use ternary operators with environment variable checking to form a connection string directly at startup time in the local/container?

While in theory if you run everything in the default network (i.e. removing `networks:` from the compose) you should be able to use `weather.db` in both cases (if you are ok with using the same container) but the "correct" answer is to use [the configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration) to provide the connection string.

Add some key to the configuration (usually it is `ConnectionStrings:SomeDbIdentifier`) and then for local environment add to the `appsettings.Development.json`:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "SomeDbIdentifier": "Data Source=..."
},
```

In the compose add environment variable:

```yaml
- ConnectionStrings__SomeDbIdentifier=Data Source=weather.db;...
```

And in the app:

```cs
// get the configuration depending on the app and the setup
Configuration.GetConnectionString("SomeDbIdentifier");
```

See also:

- [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

Comment: Thanks for pushing the idea of overriding the connection string via environment variables in Docker itself. I hadn't thought of that at all.
I use User Secrets to store the connection string, and I don't really understand how to override it like an appsettings.{Environment}.json. But the idea of overriding the connection string in the .env file for weather.api, which Docker uses directly, helped me a lot. Many thanks

Comment: @Maks0s yes, secrets are also a good source for config. Was glad to help!